# Datagrid sort bug?

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, datagrid

I'm trying to sort a DataGrid Flex component, the problem is, when I click the arrow to sort it, it seems like the sort function not only sorts the column I'm clicking, but also other columns too.

To explain it better, let say my row and columns are like these: (null is just an empty space in the grid)

> debits_***_*__*_*__** credits
>   10***_*__*_*__*_*___**(null)
>   (null)**__*_*__*_*__***11
>
>   12****_*__*_*__*_*___**(null)
>   (null)**__*_*__*_*_**_13

Now, when I click credits to sort it, this is what happens:

> debits_***_*__*_*__** credits
>   (null)**__*_*__*_*____***13
>
>   12****_*__*_*__*_*__*_***(null)
>   (null_***_*__*_*__*_*__***11
>
>   10****_*__*_*____**(null)

instead of:

> debits_***_*__*_*__** credits
>   (null)**__*_*__*_*____***13
>
>   (null****_*__*_*__*_*____***11
>
>   12****_*__*_*__*_*__**(null)
>   10***_*__*_*____**(null)

I debugged it and the compare function is receiving the 4 values, 10, 11, 12 and 13, instead of only two, 13 and 11. Which makes me wonder, why is that happening?, shouldn't the sort function only care about the column I'm sorting and not the rest?..

Anyway, the result is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

you can custom yourself sortCompareFunction.

DataGridColumn sort row's data as string, if you want compare as number, you should define the sortCompareFunction

i.e:

```
public static function numericCompare(key:String):Function
    {
        return function(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int
        {
            if (itemA == null && itemB == null)
                return 0;

            if (itemA == null)
                return 1;

            if (itemB == null)
                return -1;

            var emptyA:Boolean = StringUtil.isEmpty(itemA[key]);
            var emptyB:Boolean = StringUtil.isEmpty(itemB[key]);

            if (emptyA && emptyB)
                return 0;

            if (emptyA)
                return 1;

            if (emptyB)
                return -1;

            var num1:Number = Number(itemA[key]);
            var num2:Number = Number(itemB[key]);

            return mx.utils.ObjectUtil.numericCompare(num1, num2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that but, it is not what I'm asking. I already have a custom compare funtion, it works just fine, the problem is that when I sort a column, it doesn't only sort all the rows according that column only, but it takes into consideration other columns too and it leaves empty spaces in the selected column. Not sure how to format the "tables" I've placed in my OP, I'll give it a try.

Comment: can you give a example code? i write a example and test by myself, it's works fine.

Comment: It is kind of tricky to do that because of the magnitude of the project... it would probably mean nothing if I give you the mxmls alone. Anyway, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the sorting function, because if I don't specify one, the same weird behavior happens. Could it be, that I'm using the same datafield name for both columns?, even when I'm filling them with different data?.

Comment: yes, it's the problem. columns should be different datafield. Column sort while use the datafield as sortfield to sorting data.

Comment: But, IIRC, when you specify a sort compare function, the dataField default sorting mechanism is dismissed.

Comment: that's very strange, could you give a simple example to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the [document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#sortCompareFunction) says:

> Note: The obj1 and obj2 parameters are entire data provider elements and not just the data for the item.

So, it is normal and expected.

You may think it is strange or complicated, but many features in DataGrid use the data of its row, not just of its column.

If they only provide information about the column (or data field), but you need more information about the data, the code will get really dirty and smelly. Or, you might have to write dozens of lines of code just for that.

See, someone was in the similar situation, just yesterday: [validation in flex datagrid using itemEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23232259/474947)
(Imagine you have to sort the values field. Some values need to be parsed according to its type.)

It is convenient and saves you a lot in real world.